# Query on a self-referential table

Tags: database, postgresql, join, view

Suppose I have this simple table

```
UserID|Name  |Aid ID
  1   |Bob   | 3
  2   |Alice | 1
  3   |Ted   | 4
  4   |Sam   | 2
```

In a query, I would have to list the name of the person, and the name of the person that they aid.  I thought about doing a View, but I feel like this could be done in a simple query than creating a view.  How would I do that, and how does the query work exactly, like the fundamentals behind it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that a view is basically just saved SQL query. Neither is "simpler" than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join the table to itself

```
SELECT  a."UserID",
        a."Name",
        b."Name" As AIDName
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON a."AidID" = b."UserID"
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/305d6/4)

Comment: I don't know why I thought you could only join tables with other tables. Thanks.

Comment: What is that SQLFiddle exactly? Like shows you what happens under the hood when you issue out a command to PSQL?

Comment: it's a website used to test the query, did you click the link?

Comment: I did, just asking the obvious.  Seems pretty useful, thanks for the link. =)

Answer (score 1):

Query will be

```
select persons.name,aid.name 
from your_tablename as persons,
     your_tablename as aid
where persons.aidid=aid.userID
```